# Disabling csrf for all path and override by enabling csrf for only two path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, csrf

I searched for this question on stackoverflow but i found question where csrf is enabled and ignored for certain path.

I want to do just the opposite. I have lots of endpoints and i want to disable csrf for all path and enable for only a handful of path.

I am using spring boot and have a WebSecurityConfig class.

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(listOfEndPoints).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
        http.httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

So, I want to disable csrf for all possible endpoints and overwrite in another function where only a handful of path(two or three paths) is csrf protected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you can split your security configuration into multiple inner static class to achieve this purpose:

```
/**
 * @author slemoine
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class CsrfDisabledSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private static final String MATCHER = "/nocsrf/**";

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.antMatcher(MATCHER).authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated().and()
                    .csrf().disable();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class WithCsrfSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private static final String MATCHER = "/withcsrf/**";

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.antMatcher(MATCHER).authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(3)
    public static class VariousUriWithCsrfDisabledSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                    .antMatcher("/path1/**")
                    .antMatcher("/path2/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and().csrf().disable();
        }
    }
}
```

The first two static inner configuration show you how to set or disable csrf on a common root path. The third disables csrf on some specific paths.

Or if you want a more direct implementation answering your question:

```
/**
 * @author slemoine
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class VariousUriWithCsrfEnabledSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                    .antMatcher("/path1/**")
                    .antMatcher("/path2/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();

        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class CsrfDisabledSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated().and()
                    .csrf().disable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the second approach(CsrfDisabledSecurityConfig) overwrite the first one(VariousUriWithCsrfEnabledSecurityConfig) thus disabling csrf.

Comment: No the first SecurityFilterChain takes precedence due to the @Order(1) if the url is /path1/** or /path2/**.

Comment: I double checked it, try to put a breakpoint on CsrfFilter class and DefaultSecurityFilterChain (matches method) it should be okay according to your needs.